# Scroll bar not working

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to produce list of recently added item in cart and the code goes like this

```
<ol style = "overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; overflow-y: scroll;">
        <?php foreach($_items as $_item): ?>
            <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ol>
```

I'm getting the items but the scroll not working. Please help me. I'm a budding developer.

Comment: You need to set a height shorter than the list.

Answer (score 1):

use `overflow:auto` property of css instead of `scroll`, and give some `height` for your list.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have vertical scroll after certain height of ol container use below listed code

`<ol style = "overflow-y: scroll;">`

Comment: you can set ol with fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

Specify a height there like this

```
<ol style = "overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; overflow-y: scroll;height:50px;">
 <?php foreach($_items as $_item): ?>
 <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</ol>
```